# How to calculate power dissipation for an MT3608L current-mode step-up converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, power-dissipation

I'm using an [MT3608L](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201121530_XI-AN-Aerosemi-Tech-MT3608L_C2932326.pdf) with an input voltage of 12 V to create a voltage of 18 V using the below schematic. As this is a cutout of a larger schematic, the input voltage is applied to the top left wire, the bottom is GND (obvious, but want to avoid confusion).

[image: Schematic MT3608L]

I'm using the 18 V to drive a bunch of LEDs for background lighting. The current going to my LEDs in total is about 300 mA max, so far below the spec of 2.5 A.

When using a normal linear voltage regulator like the AMS1117, you have to watch out for power dissipation in the regulator. This depends on the output current, but also the voltage drop Vout - Vin. But there, it's obvious that all the current flows through the regulator, hence power is being dissipated.

But how do I calculate the power dissipation of the MT3608L? Or does that make no sense, because the current is not running through the chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMS1117 is a *linear regulator*, it can only reduce voltage, and the input current is roughly the same as the output current. The excess power P = (V<sub>in</sub> - V<sub>out</sub>) · I is dissipated as heat.

A DC/DC converter is a different beast; it converts input power P<sub>in</sub> =  V<sub>in</sub> · I<sub>in</sub> to output power P<sub>out</sub> =  V<sub>out</sub> · I<sub>out</sub>, usually by using switching techniques and energy storage in a coil.

At 100% efficiency, P<sub>in</sub> = P<sub>out</sub>. No DC/DC converter is a 100% efficient, of course. The efficiency at different loads/output currents can be found in the datasheet (usually in the 80-95% range), and this will give you an idea of the losses/power dissipated as heat in the DC/DC converter's *circuit*.

Part of the losses/dissipation will be in the IC, the rest in other components in the circuit.

There is no general formula for calculating the power dissipation in an arbitrary DC/DC converter IC, so you will have to consult the datasheet.